# Error showing all images from a directory

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to show all the images in a specific directory. To do this, I'm using openCV for python. However I get the following error when running my code.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'
```

I think some kind of error occurs while loading in the image, but I'm not sure how. Does someone understand what I'm doing wrong?

```
import cv2
import os

for filename in os.listdir('images'):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: **Assertion failed:** size.width>0 && size.height>0  - you either have a non-image or a zero size image ... did you put a try:catch: around it and inspect the faulty file?

Comment: It is a working image. If I load it in outside of the for loop with a direct path, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. Since I'm iterating over all images in a given directory, I should also open the images from this drectory.

img = cv2.imread('images/' + filename)

This did the job for me